# passing value from product to price list item crm2015

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-online

I have custom field called total ("new_test_total")and the field is calculated from two other field[image]

and I want to pass these total to the price list item  amount what I have been done so far

I created another custom field called test and make these function on change the field Total amount

to pass the value of total amount to the field i create "new_test"

```
function update_Amount(){   Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_test").setValue(Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_test_total").getValue());}
```

and make mapping between price list item and Product

between the field test and the field amount

[image]

it works fine but when I try to change the field total by changing the parameter that it calculated based on it

the total amount change but i must save it twice(ctrl+s) to change the value of amount in price list item

Answer (score -1):

I solved these problem by creating these function to change the field data based on the change of the meterfield or the change of the gross field

```
function update_test(){var x=Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_grossarea").getValue();var y=Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_meterprice").getValue();Xrm.Page.data.entity.attributes.get("new_test").setValue(x*y);}
```

and when the field new_grossarea changed i call the above function
and when the new_meterprice changed i call the above function also
and save the form the field amount in price list item is also changed based on the change of the field